# Type error in mean stack post method

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express

**MEAN Stack**

I keep getting

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'first_name' of undefined

when trying to execute this code (all variables, including modules are defined in other parts of the code). While using GET Method, my code is working fine. But for POST Method, it throws error. Attached the screenshot below.

[Advance Rest Client POST Method Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0N502.png)

Added my code below.

Thanks in advance

```js
//app.js
//Importing Modules

var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyparser = require('body-parser');
var cors = require('cors');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();

//port Number
const port = 3000;

const route = require('./routes/route');

//Connect to MongoDB
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/contactlist');

//if connected
mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
  console.log("Mongo DB Connected successfully");
});

//if not connected
mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error in connecting to the MongoDB');
  }
});

//adding middleware cors
app.use(cors());

//routes will happen here
app.use('/api', route);

//adding middleware
app.use(bodyparser.json());

//Static files
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//Testing
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello Vinoth");
});

app.get('/yahoo', (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello Vinoth");
});

//Connection
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("Server started at port:" + port);
});
```

```js
//route.js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const Contact = require('../models/contacts');

// retrieving details
router.get('/contacts', (req, res, next) => {
  Contact.find(function(err, contacts) {
    res.json(contacts);
  });
});

// Add Contacts
//Add contact
router.post('/contact', (res, req, next) => {
  console.log('Insides');
  let newContact = new Contact({
    first_name: req.body.first_name,
    last_name: req.body.last_name,
    phone: req.body.phone
  });

  newContact.save((err, contact) => {
    if (err) {
      res.json({
        msg: 'Failed to add contact'
      });
    } else {
      res.json({
        msg: 'Contact added successfully'
      });
    }
  });
});

// Delete Contacts
router.delete('/contact/:id', (req, res, next) => {
  Contact.remove({
    _id: req.params.id
  }, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      res.json(err);
    } else {
      res.json(result);
    }
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

```js
//contacts.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const ContactSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  first_name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  last_name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  phone: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

const Contact = module.exports = mongoose.model('Contact', ContactSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving `app.use(bodyparser.json())` before `app.use('/api', route)`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to Declare

```
//adding middleware
app.use(bodyparser.json());
```

Before use all routes. So you need to update your `app.js` like:

```
//adding middleware
app.use(bodyparser.json());

//routes will happen here
app.use('/api', route);
```

In additional you need to refactor your `route.js`
 code like this:

```
//Add contact
router.post('/contact', (res, req, next) => {

    const {
        first_name,
        last_name,
        phone
    } = req.body;

    let newContact = new Contact({
        first_name,
        last_name,
        phone
    });

    newContact.save((err, contact) => {

        if (err) {
            res.json({
                msg: 'Failed to add contact'
            });
        } else {
            res.json({
                msg: 'Contact added successfully'
            });
        }

        });
});
```

Comment: The above solution is not working for me. Still i am getting same error.

Comment: You need to also move `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));` this line of code before `app.use('/api', route);`